# Face Recognition with Android and PHP

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to create a face recognition system. I want to make with a combination of android and php. User can take a picture with a phone and android application will send picture to php server and php server will recognize face from the database and sends response back to the cell phone.

I have made an application that detects face and saves only face of a person using opencv. I can send that picture to server as well. My problem is I dont know how can I use opencv library with php. Opencv tutorial is very confusing and it is in C++. I dont know how can I run C++ code on server.
So my question is, is it possible to run Opencv libraries with php or I can run C++ on server.
I am a beginner with Opencv. Please help

Comment: Why not just run the detection oh the handset?

Comment: It could be very expensive, depending on the size of his database.

Comment: @mjs I will have a big set of images to look for a face. Since cell phone has a limitation of a memory, I would like to do it on a server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, PHP can call an external program (the C++ face recognizer) if it doesn't mind waiting around:
[PHP: exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

The smoother solution would be to provide an interface for the PHP in the C++ program, but that does not seem to be your language.

But what about **Python**? It's quite simple to have Python respond to web queries, and OpenCV wrappers exist for it. You could do it all in one place that way.

Comment: I am not so familiar with python. Surely, I will look for it. Thanks